# Assigning 2d array in vector of indices

Tags: python

Given 2d array `k = np.zeros((M, N))` and list of indices in the range `0, 1 .., M-1` of size `N` called `places = np.random.random_integers(0, M-1, N)` how do I assign 1 in each column of `k` in the `places[i]` index where i is running index.
I would like to achieve that in python compact style and without any loops

Examples:

```
N = 5, M =3
places= 0, 0, 1, 1, 2
```

Then:

```
k = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0
     0, 0, 1, 1, 0
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rslt = np.zeros((M, N))
for i, v in enumerate(places): rslt[v,i]=1
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
M=3
#places = np.random.random_integers(0, M-1, N)
places= 0, 0, 1, 1, 2
rslt = np.zeros((M, N))
for i, v in enumerate(places): rslt[v,i]=1
print(rslt)

Out [34]:
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```